# Why does kivy root.manager return None?

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently building an app for self measurement. I've faced the following problem : I want to have a result screen, with progress bars for my achievements. So far it looks like this:

```
<ResultScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Назад, к музыке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'music'
        ProgressBar:
            max : 1000
            value : root.manager.get_screen('music').slider.value
```

The problem is, `root.manager` works fine when applied to the `Button` and returns to the given screen. However in `ProgressBar` it appears to be `None` and returns the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'`

What is wrong?

The full code:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class PongScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MusicScreen(Screen):
    pass
class DiscreteScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ResultScreen(Screen):
    pass
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(PongScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(MusicScreen(name='music'))   
        sm.add_widget(DiscreteScreen(name='discrete')) 
        sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result')) 
     
        return sm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MusicScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Назад в меню'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Дальше, к дискретке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'discrete'
        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0
            max: 20
            step: 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Тактов выучено\n' + str(slider.value)
            
        CheckBox:
            id : new_song_checkbox
        Label:
            text : 'Новую песню выучил?\n' + str(new_song_checkbox.active)
        CheckBox:
            id : music_pleasure_checkbox
        Label:
            text : 'Доволен ли исполнением\n' + str(music_pleasure_checkbox.active)
            
<DiscreteScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'В меню'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Назад, к музыке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'music'
        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0
            max: 180
            step: 15
            orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Минут на код затрачено\n' + str(slider.value)
            
        CheckBox:
            id : article_checkbox
        Label:
            text : 'Статью прочитал?\n' + str(article_checkbox.active)
        CheckBox:
            id : lecture_checkbox
        Label:
            text : 'Посмотрел ли лекцию?\n' + str(lecture_checkbox.active)
            
<DiscreteScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'В меню'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Назад, к музыке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'music'
        Button:
            text: 'Дальше, к результатам'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'result'
        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0
            max: 180
            step: 15
            orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Минут на код затрачено\n' + str(slider.value)
            
        CheckBox:
            id : article_checkbox
        Label:
            text : 'Статью прочитал?\n' + str(article_checkbox.active)
        CheckBox:
            id : lecture_checkbox
        Label:
            text : 'Посмотрел ли лекцию?\n' + str(lecture_checkbox.active)
            
<ResultScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Назад, к музыке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'music'
        ProgressBar:
            max : 1000
            value : root.manager.get_screen('music').slider.value
<PongScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'К музыке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'music'
        Button:
            text: 'К дискретке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'discrete'
        Button:
            text: 'К результатам'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'result'
        Button:
            text: 'Выход'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `value : root.manager.get_screen('music').slider.value` is wrong because `root.manager.get_screen('music')` is supposed to be a `Screen` object and by default it doesn't have (also not in your code) any prop. `slide`.

Perhaps you mean `value : root.manager.get_screen('music').ids.slider.value`. But this will not solve your problem. Let's try to analyze the problem in simple way.

When the method `run` is called, the kv-rules are applied (by method [`load_kv`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv)) first then method `build` is called. In the method `build` you defined `ScreenManager` first thereafter added the `Screens` and described the screens in `kvlang`. Now when it encounters your `.kv` file and looks for `root.manager` (in `value : root.manager.get_screen('music').ids.slider.value`) it finds `None` (the default value, as it has not yet been added to `ScreenManager`, defined in your `build` method). That's the reason behind the `AttributeError`.

Now to solve this issue one of many ways could be,

1. You delay the value assigning process by a (built-in or custom) method like `on_enter` etc. as,

```py
<ResultScreen>:
    on_enter: pb.value = self.manager.get_screen('music').ids.slider.value
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Назад, к музыке'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'music'
        ProgressBar:
            id: pb
            max : 1000
```

2. Set a conditional statement (likely to be preferable) as,

```py
        ProgressBar:
            id: pb
            max : 1000
            value : root.manager.get_screen('music').ids.slider.value if root.manager is not None else 0
```

3. Define the `root` (i.e. `ScreenManager` here) entirely in `kvlang`.

Other ways could be creating a property for `slide.value` in the associate class; manage it in the `build` method etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I have a question: why then it doesn't throw `AttributeError` when `root.manager.current` in buttons is encountered?

UPD I think it is because it is `on_press` function, and at the moment it is called, `root` already exists, whereas for `get_screen` it is not so due to its initialization at the beginning of the problem. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but you can make it (`get_screen`) happen (just like `on_press`) otherwise when triggered or scheduled etc.